# Windows System log: showing last .EXEs executed?

Tags: windows, logging

I am on windows 7 with adminstrator privileges.

Is there an event log that can show me all the  .exe files executed in the last 2 hours (for example) ?

Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default. You could turn on file system auditing and filter for certain files. Look at the audit policy under local security policy.